# Git: Is there internal registry if you clone a repository?

Tags: git

I'm new to git and recently I have cloned the SciPy repository with its github link because I wanted to understand how some things function internally.

Now I want to move the cloned folder - or delete it again. I am wondering whether I can do this as I would normally move/delete a folder or if there is some internal registry that I would mess up by doing this.

If there is, how do you move or delete a cloned git repository in a clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply delete folder. There is no internal registry or something similar.

Comment: To expand on this: given default options, everything Git uses to manage a repository is stored inside the `.git/` directory within that repository.

Comment: And, because the `.git` is under the working tree top level directory by default, you can also just rename the working tree as desired.